# Check status of Mysql replication

Tags: php, mysql, database-replication

I am using Centos 6.7.

I have mysql database on my two servers and i have created the replication (Master - Master) on both.

Now i want to check the status of replication that is it working fine or not.

I have searched and found that **repadmin /showrepl** will give the status of all replication. But this command is not available in my centos.

I am interested to make this alert using PHP.

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can show slave status will help?
SLAVE_RUNNING, SLAVE_IO_RUNNING, SLAVE_SQL_RUNNING this parameters are looking useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-script-check-mysql-replication-status/

It have given exactly what i need for my requirement.

Edit:

Command on link above is: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` . For someone only need run command to check.

Thanks @PaPu for suggestion

Comment: Command on link above is: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` . For someone only need run command to check

Comment: I updated by answer @PaPu